# Creating columns of a dataframe in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I need help on a pandas issue:

I have a function which returns a pandas series as a result, which looks like the following:

```
 date       number
2018-01-01     1
2018-02-01     2
2018-03-01     3
2018-04-01     3
```

And I call this function within a for loop. The for loop does the following:

```
for i in range(len(category_list)):
    print(category_list[i])
    serie = filter_users_pageNS(data, new_index, category_list[i])
    serie = pd.DataFrame(serie).reset_index()
```

Where `category_list` is just the number of iterations to be done that contains the parameter to be passed to the `filter_users_pageNS` function.

My intention is to append the `number` column obtained on each iteration in a dataframe, so that at the end of the for loop, I get the following dataframe:

```
date      number_iteration_1      number_iteration_2
2018-01-01       1                       4
2018-02-01       2                       1
2018-03-01       3                       5
2018-04-01       3                       2
```

As you can see, the final dataframe has the `number` column added to the dataframe, with the name `number_iteration_x`.

Any ideas on how to get this final dataframe?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please post your function code so we can help you.

Comment: what is the logic of the second iteration?

Comment: Hi, I just edited the question. Maybe now you know how to help me

Comment: @HRDSL we still do not know the logic behind the output

Comment: You should provide code for `filter_users_pageNS` as well. In most cases, you can bypass the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, something along these lines should work:

```
df=df.reset_index()
for i in range(len(category_list)):
    print(category_list[i])
    serie = filter_users_pageNS(data, new_index, category_list[i])
    serie = pd.DataFrame(serie).reset_index()
    df['number_iteration_'+str(i)]=serie
```

Edit: Adjusted answer based on your new data

Comment: This didn't work, i can't concatenate the i just like that. Returned error is:TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: Sorry, missed the `str` part. This should do now